# How to use HttpPatch in API correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API with player model. I got a serious problem on HttpPatch. name of player to update should not be the same as any other player name. The problem is when I want to update other properties of my player (including position or nationality) It still fails to complete the task! Here is my code

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> UpdatePlayer(Player player, int id)
    {

        if (player == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (player.Id != id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        if (await _applicationDbContext.Players.AnyAsync(p => p.Name == player.Name))
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
        }
        await _playerRepository.UpdatePlayer(player);
        return Ok(player);
    }
```

Comment: `p.Name == player.Name` will match the player you're trying to update. Basically, unless you're changing the name along with some other property, this condition is always `true`

Comment: I know that, But I can't figure it out! It compares the player with the player to be updated and as they have same names, It returns to the condition and fails to be completed

Comment: `p => p.Name == player.Name && p.Id != player.Id` - basically, is there a player object with the same name, but a different id

Comment: In general, I don't really understand what this method does - why take a `Player` that has an `Id` *and* also separately an `id`???

Comment: You saved me @CoolBots ! Thanks